# Histogram of Counts by Bin

Tags: r

I have a dataset that looks like the following:

```
     X1   X2 
546   1   7.893310 
547   0   9.723409 
548   0   9.256349  
549   1 -21.008398 
550   5   0.151026
```

I'd like to create a histogram with bins of X2 on the X axis. The y axis needs to contain sums of X1 by bin(not frequencies). How do I go about doing this?

Comment: It's NOT a histogram. Er, well, I suppose it could be if those were frequencies of some sort.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

take a look at `cut` to bin your data.  then `tapply` for your sums.

```
> dat$cuts <- cut(dat$X2, c(-Inf, 0, 8, 16, Inf))

> dat
    X1         X2     cuts
546  1   7.893310    (0,8]
547  0   9.723409   (8,16]
548  0   9.256349   (8,16]
549  1 -21.008398 (-Inf,0]
550  5   0.151026    (0,8]
> 
> tapply(dat$X1, dat$cuts, sum)
 (-Inf,0]     (0,8]    (8,16] (16, Inf] 
     1         6         0        NA
```

Then you can plot many different ways, the simplest:

```
barplot(tapply(dat$X1, dat$cuts, sum))
```